# Set eclipse ee preference for mac osx lion

Tags: python, eclipse, osx-leopard

I have a mac (osx lion). I have installed eclipse (Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Indigo Release; Build id: 20110615-0604). And I have installed the python plugins, following instructions from http://www.rose-hulman.edu/class/csse/resources/Eclipse/eclipse-python-configuration.htm. Now, according to the instructions, I need to set the python executable path in the eclipse preference.

Now I know mac comes with a version of python installed. And doing "whereis python" at the terminal reveals that it is in usr/bin/. But which file is the python exe? (I am new to mac: one week; I am completely new to python: less than one day).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you tried /user/bin/python and it did not work. ( It worked for me while setting up my pycharm ide)..

Then provide the following path as your python Interpreter path.

> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin

(of course, your path might be slightly different).

Comment: Thanks, it works. When you get to the next page "select the folders to be added to the SYSTEM pythonpath" do you select everything?

Comment: hmm... It depends on how you installed .. bt in general you need to provide the lib folder and extras folder inside (//versions/2.6) directory.